# How low of temperature can hot pepper plants tolerate?

Tags: chili, frost, cold-weather

How low of of temperatures can my hot pepper plants (I have a few different types) tolerate overnight?  What about the fruit (some is ripe, some is not) on the plants?  I have a few nights forecasted as lows of 38 F coming up and am wondering if I need to move them indoors or into the garage.  All the plants are in pots if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5):

They should be fine as long as it doesn't actually freeze. I grow them in Montana and they are very susceptible to frost, but only if it actually frosts. If the peppers are touched by frost, they get soft and mushy.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much of a risk-taker you are. Temperature for the weather is taken in the air (rather than ground level). It can be colder on the ground, which is why it can frost when it's up to 41° F. However, in my experience, in my garden (in SW Idaho), most (not all) frosts that occur when the weather says it's above freezing (above 32° F.) are pretty mild, and they tend to damage foliage more than fruit. However, it's still risky to some degree.

Some kinds of peppers are supposed to handle light frosts better than others, but you're safer treating them all about the same as tomatoes.